# CSV Data config - avoid creating duplicate folder names

Tags: jmeter

I have created CSV data config as attached and the purpose of this run is to create folder names in the application and should not try to create the duplicate folder names.

please advise if we need to add post processor with if condition? if yes please provide the condition to put in post processor?

Answer (score 0):

I can only think of getting the existing folder names somehow and storing them into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html)

Once done you can use the [If Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/six-tips-for-jmeter-if-controller-usage) and use the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) as the condition:

```
${__groovy(!vars.entrySet().collect {entry -> entry.getValue()}.contains(vars.get('your variable from CSV Data Set Config')),)}
```

The If Controllers child(ren) will only be executed if there is no JMeter Variable with the value of the current variable from the CSV Data Set Config is present.